# How to programmatically disable ECB menu item for a particular list item?

Tags: sharepoint, menu, emacs-ecb

I have a custom document library which is based on default document library. I'd like to disable **Edit** physical document for some of the documents depending on their property.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a client side solution then you can use either a single Content Editor Web Part to inject some JavaScript on a single page or execute the script on every page in the site collection using our free [SharePoint Infuser](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Infuser-(Free).aspx).

Plenty of examples, although not your particular problem, [can be found here](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/labels/Infuser.html).

Comment: it looks as a possible way but I'd like to have less hackish way :)